# Do I need to reserve ICE train from Germany to Belgium with first-class rail pass?

Tags: trains, germany, bookings, belgium, eurail

I'll be travelling with a *first-class* Germany-Benelux rail pass, and I'm planning to take an ICE train from Cologne (Germany) to Brussels (Belgium). Will I need to reserve a seat for this train? I don't know how I can find out this information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to find out whether you need a reservation on a certain train is to look up the train in a rail planner.
I use the [German planner](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/DEU/en/index.shtml) for this, as it is easy to use and gives good information.

Enter the cities you want to travel and adjust date and time of day, if traveling more than a few months from the time you check, just pick a random date but try to use the same day of the week, and hit search.

In the results you will find trains with an R, a grey dot with a white R means compulsory reservation, they also have a different R for recommended reservation.
Click on the orange arrow before the results and you get details.

The train you mention was in the results I got without reservation notice with it, so you can get on it without a reservation, also when you hold a rail pass.

For first class travel I might not bother with reservations but for second class long distance travel I do make them when possible. Trains do tend to fill up, also when you do not expect them to.

Answer (score 5):

On that route and train (ICE) reservation is optional and costs 4 EUR with the kind of pass you have:

http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/reservation-guide/reservation-fees/international-train-reservation-fees

Here is infomation on how you can book it:

http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/guide-eurail-train-reservations/how-do-i-book-my-reservations

Answer (score 0):

Reservations are optional on most ICE trains, notably including those Cologne–Brussels. Since you are travelling first class, there will be seats available, so there will be no need to reserve.